# conditionally extracting from raster within a buffer

Tags: r, gis

I have a raster that has stored values ranging from 1 to 10.

How can I extract and sum the amount of pixels within a buffer for each of the values? So that I have total number of pixels with value 1, 2, etc. within the buffer of specified size.

```
los <- function(x, cent, buff) {

    xmin <- x@extent@xmin
    xmax <- x@extent@xmax
    ymin <- x@extent@ymin
    ymax <- x@extent@ymax

    cent2 <- filter(cent, (Long<=xmax & Long>=xmin), (Lat<=ymax & 
Lat>=ymin))

    coordinates(cent) <- ~Long+Lat

    buffer <- extract(x, cent, buffer=buff, fun=???, 
df=TRUE)

return(buffer)
}
```

Comment: instead of `filter`, you can do `cent <- instersect(cent, x)` after transforming `cent` to a `SpatialPointsDF` object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is some example data

```
library(raster)
r <- raster(ncol=36, nrow=18, vals=sample(5, 36*18, replace=TRUE))
xy <- cbind(-50, seq(-80, 80, by=20))[1:3,]
```

You can use `extract` with `tabulate`

```
maxvalue <- maxValue(r)  
e <- extract(r, xy[1:3,], buffer=1000000, fun=function(x) tabulate(x, maxvalue))
matrix(e, ncol=maxvalue, byrow=T)
```

Or

```
maxvalue <- maxValue(r)  
e <- extract(r, xy[1:3,], buffer=1000000)
t(sapply(e, function(x) tabulate(x, maxvalue)))

#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
#[1,]    1    3    5    5    6
#[2,]    4    2    0    0    0
#[3,]    1    2    0    1    0
```